# Stop color from resetting between different scatterplot instances

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making 1D plots of a number of data columns using scatter plots. Each instance in each column has a label which represents some atribute. In the 1D plot this label is displayed using a colour.

It's something as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# make data points
data1 = [i for i in range(100)]
data2 = [i for i in range(100)]
data3 = [i for i in range(100)]

# make labels
label1 = [1 for _ in range(50)] + [2 for _ in range(50)]
label2 = [3 for _ in range(50)] + [4 for _ in range(50)]
label3 = [5 for _ in range(50)] + [6 for _ in range(50)]

# combine into dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'data1':data1, 'data2':data2, 'data3':data3, 'label1':label1, 'label2':label2, 'label3':label3})

# make figure
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(df['data1'], [0 for _ in range(df['data1'].shape[0])], c=df['label1'])
plt.scatter(df['data2'], [1 for _ in range(df['data2'].shape[0])], c=df['label2'])
plt.scatter(df['data3'], [2 for _ in range(df['data3'].shape[0])], c=df['label3'])
plt.yticks(ticks=[0,1,2], labels=['data1', 'data2', 'data3'])
plt.show()
```

Note, each data column has its own label column and the labels are different. For `data1` this is `1,2` for `data2` `3,3` and for `data3` `5,6`. When I make my 1D plots here each of the points get the same colors. So for `data1` labels 1 and 2 are the same color as labels 3 and 4 in `data2` etc.

My question is how can I make each label have its own color in the plot such that 1,3,5 and 2,4,6 do not have the same color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `vmin, vmax` to `scatter`:

```
# vmin, vmax can be obtained by
# vmin, vmax = df.filter(like='label').stack().agg(['min','max'])

# make figure
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(df['data1'], [0] * len(df['data1']), c=df['label1'], vmin=1, vmax=6)
plt.scatter(df['data2'], [1] * len(df['data2']), c=df['label2'], vmin=1, vmax=6)
plt.scatter(df['data3'], [2] * len(df['data3']), c=df['label3'], vmin=1, vmax=6)
plt.yticks(ticks=[0,1,2], labels=['data1', 'data2', 'data3'])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]